# does not have a matching glue code in Groovy-cucumber

Tags: maven, groovy, cucumber

I'm using `cucumber-groovy` with maven based framework and unable to find the glue to stepDefinitions. Getting **does not have a matching glue code** in feature file. It is in Cucumber-maven Project. I have converted the Feature folder to 'Source folder'.

**Error :**

```
Unable to create src/test/groovy & src/test/resource (to use as feature's folder)
```

Here is my Test Runner CucumberOptions:

```
@CucumberOptions( features = ["src/test/resources/"],
        glue = ["com.esw.taa.avs.steps"],
        plugin = ["html:esw-tests/report"],
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = true,
        strict = true
        )
```

[image: cucumber groovy folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

I also use Groovy-cucumber, but without Maven. Here is my CucumberOptions:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = "pretty",
    monochrome = true,
    tags = "not @wip",
    features = "src/test/resources/Features",
    glue = {"test.java.StepDefinitions"},
    junit = "--step-notifications"
    )
```