# In Eclipse, Cucumber feature steps not recognizing step definitions

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, serenity-bdd

My Runner class is as below:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/"
    ,glue={"com.stepdefs"}
    ,dryRun=false
    ,monochrome=true
    ,plugin = {pretty})

public class Runner {
}
```

I don't have any issues with executing them using maven. It works totally fine. Only the issue with Eclipse where feature steps can't recognize any step defs. So i can't find them using F3. I have added this below dependency as well:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

As well i converted the project to cucumber project, added cucumber plugins in Eclipse. My Eclipse version is 2020-12. Still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked in the compiled files for Eclipse to see if stuff is there in the expected place? Maven/Gradle create them elsewhere (.m1 for Maven, if memory serves), so it's not a given that Maven being able to run it means Eclipse can run it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using cucumber6, I think this is an existing issue for cucumber 4 and up:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/372

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/368

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I have the class name as part of the definition, e.g:

```
glue={"com.stepdefs.StepDefinitions"}
```

Comment: I tried this below:  glue={"com.stepdefs", "com.stepdefs.A_StepDef" , "com.stepdefs.B_StepDef", "com.stepdefs.C_StepDef"}   Here  com.stepdefs  is the package name.

Comment: Didn't help either

Comment: Here's a previous answer I gave: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59980602/3355860

Comment: I don't think your issue is the glue itself. If so, you could set it to "com" and pick things up because it looks everywhere down that package path.

Comment: @Taelus Looks like this is an existing cucumber version issue: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/372